# Ordering a multidimensional array in python

Tags: python

I have a data structure like:

```
[ ["id1", 123], ["id2", 1], ["id3", 6] ]
```

and I would like to ordered it (descendingly) according to the second variable, like this:

```
[ ["id1", 123], ["id3", 6], ["id2", 1] ]
```

I could write up a little function for doing that, but I am almost sure there's a cool one liner way of doing it, isn't there? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using `sorted` and `itemgetter`:

```
>>> a = [ ["id1", 123], ["id2", 1], ["id3", 6] ]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[['id1', 123], ['id3', 6], ['id2', 1]]
```

If you purely wanted a one-liner (no import), then you can `lambda` it:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda L: L[1], reverse=True)
```